# Service 'McpManagementService (McpManagementService)' cannot be queried due to the following error:

Tags: powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I am trying to run this in PowerShell7

```
PS C:\Users\MYUSER> $myoutput = get-service| where-Object Status -eq "Stopped"| select-Object Name, Status
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
Get-Service: Service 'McpManagementService (McpManagementService)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
```

How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

I think problem described there:

[PowerShell GitHub Issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10371#issuecomment-1459112449)

**Solution** (not the best)
Just ignore an error something like:

```
Get-Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not work. I keep getting "Get-Service: The resource loader failed to find MUI file."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like powershell is not able to pull the data for one or more services. Hence, this error message. if you extract the data from $myoutput variable, you should see the output for rest of the services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).